# Attempted to ssh as root after running into Denied error, but couldn't login

Tags: permissions, root

I'm running a Plex server on my RPi3 with Raspberry OS Lite.

I've started running into an error when uploading files that I cannot set permissions/timestamp, error 3 Denied.

I've tried a few things, one being to log in as root. I've changed the password and enabled root login via `sshd_config`.

But, when I try to ssh as root, it still says the password is wrong and will not allow me to ssh into the root account.

Comment: Did you do anything recently that caused it? The first step is to trace what happened that caused this to happen. Think back to what you did before that issue happened. The second step is to see why it is doing that. Maybe it is interfering with something or editing something in the system that caused it to break. The third step is to fix it. Remove what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry OS Lite doesn't have a root user!

Login as pi or another user (if you have created one) and use `sudo` to perform actions that needs elevated credentials.

And please post complete error messages and use the {} button to format it as code!

Comment: what? How come RPi OS Lite doesn't have a root user? Doesn't all linux distributions have a root?

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 Debian derived OS don't have a root **USER** which you can login to although it is possible to create one. There is a root account which you can access with sudo su.

Comment: @Milliways - in Debian you don't need to "create one" as you say, you just add a password to `root` and the existing root user can now be logged in to. `root` **USER** exists in Debian, just that logging in to `root` is *disabled* by virtue of the password field in `/etc/shadow` being `*` (like many other system accounts)

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought.

Comment: @JaromandaX if you can't login you DON'T have a root USER. Adding a password enables login to the root account.

Comment: @Milliways - we can argue semantics all day - root account vs root user